# Finding one sided limit using L'Hospital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(x^\sqrt{x}\right)=?$

How do I turn it into a fraction? Is L'Hospital's rule even applicable?

Comment: You could try using logarithms

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Consider $\log$, so $\sqrt{x}\log x=\dfrac{\log x}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}$.

Answer (score -1):

given limit = $e^{\sqrt{x}\ln x} $

we know $\ln x < (x-1) < x $

$0 \leq\sqrt{x}\ln x <  \sqrt{x} x $

this limit converges to 0 as $x\to 0$ by squeeze theorem

i.e., given limit converges to $e^0= 1$ as $x \to 0$